# (Non)degenerate transformation of variables in bilinear functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two quadratic functions $\varphi, \psi:V\to \mathbb{k}$ and there is a linear change of variables (not necessary nondegenerate) which transforms $\varphi$ to $\psi$, and change of variables which transforms $\psi$ to $\varphi$. Show that these two functions are equivalent, i.e. there is nondegenerate change of variable transforming one of them to the other.

**My approach:** Let $\varphi(x)=X^tAX$ and $\psi(y)=Y^tBY$, where $X,Y$ are column of coordinates of $x$ and $y$, respectively. Suppose that $X=C_1Y$ transforming $\varphi$ into $\psi$ and $Y=C_2 X$ transforming $\psi$ into $\varphi$.

More precisely, $$\varphi(C_1Y)=(C_1Y)^tA(C_1Y)=Y^t(C_1^tAC_1)Y=Y^tBY$$ and $$\psi(C_2X)=(C_2X)^tB(C_2X)=X^t(C_2^tBC_2)X=X^tAX.$$

Or it can be written in this way $Y^t(C_1^tAC_1-B)Y=0$ and $X^t(C_2^tBC_2-A)X=0$. Since the matrices in parentheses are symmetric then it follows that: $$C_1^tAC_1=B \ \text{and} \ C_2^tBC_2=A$$ or $$A=(C_1C_2)^tA(C_1C_2).$$

Also note that $X=C_1Y=(C_1C_2)X$, i.e. $(E-C_1C_2)X=0$ and since this is true for all $X$ then $E=C_1C_2$ and it follows that $\det C_1\neq 0$ and $\det C_2\neq 0$. But the problem stated that $C_1$ may be degenerate transformation.

And this confuses me a lot!

I would be very thankful if someone will explain my question and shows how to finish this problem. I guess that my reasoning is correct!